# Exclude credit cards from Google Pay

Tags: android, google-pay

It was recently announced that as of April 2020, gambling via credit cards will be banned in the UK. As such, I need to exclude credit cards from Google Pay so that the user can't select one as a payment method.

I know that I can exclude specific card networks like so:

```
private static JSONArray getAllowedCardNetworks() {
  return new JSONArray()
      .put("AMEX")
      .put("DISCOVER")
      .put("INTERAC");
      .put("JCB")
      .put("MASTERCARD")
      .put("VISA");
}
```

However given that a card network can provide both debit and credit cards it doesn't make sense to exclude using networks.

There is also the option to exclude prepaid cards via

```
allowPrepaidCards
```

But I can't see anything about excluding either credit or debit cards, is this not supported?

**Edit:**

Having spoken with Google they gave me the following response, I will update when this feature is available. In the meantime follow Sams advice.

> Thank you for reaching out. Unfortunately, we currently don't have a
>   way of excluding credit cards from Google Pay API.   We are aware of
>   this and we are reviewing the possible options we have to enable this
>   feature. Please let us check with the product the roadmap of this
>   feature and we will get back to you.

Comment: Did they tell anything after that? Do they have a date in plan for when this will be available? Thanks.

Comment: @tasegula they're aiming to release an update to the GPay library sometime in March, apparently it's going to be a simple toggle much like the allowPrepaidCards flag so it shouldn't take too long for us to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is now available, although the documentation hasn't bee updated yet.

See example web implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/6983ofu2/

```js
const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
  type: 'CARD',
  parameters: {
    allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods,
    allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks,
    allowCreditCards: false
  }
};
```

Would be interesting to see if it works for Android as well.

Comment: This works on Android so I'm marking it as the answer, I was a little dubious as the GPay library hasn't actually been updated but since we're building the request as JSON I suppose it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the documentation and the closest information I can understand is after you get receive the `PaymentData` you can check the card type using [`getCardClass()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/CardInfo.html#public-int-getcardclass-)

```
PaymentData paymentData = PaymentData.getFromIntent(intent);
if (paymentData.getCardInfo().getCardClass() != WalletConstants.CARD_CLASS_DEBIT) {
    // show error to user
}
else
{
    // proceed to payment.
}
```

Reading the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/InstrumentInfo), the return type of `getCardClass` is `int` which indicates as follows :

- Constant Value : 1 = **CARD_CLASS_CREDIT**
- Constant Value : 2 = **CARD_CLASS_DEBIT**
- Constant Value : 3 = **CARD_CLASS_PREPAID**
- Constant Value : 4 = **CARD_CLASS_UNKNOWN**

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be good if we could exclude them from the payment screen itself so the user doesn't have the ability to choose a credit card but this works as a temporary work around. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ScottCooper As per my research so far, I haven't seen any API documentation in which we can identify it as a credit or debit card. If you find anything, do post it here. This might be helpful to others looking for something similar.

Comment: @Sam. Have you tried this? `paymentData.getCardInfo()` is actually null. Tried in their sample app as well, and it's `null` also. Any idea how we can get that `InstrumentInfo` from `PaymentData`? I can't seem to find anything.